# How to use where date(timeline) in Laravel Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

```
select count(*) from laporan where date(w_laporan) = date(timestamps)
```

How can I use this query in Laravel 5 query builder?
Thanks.

Comment: i mean date(timestamps)

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
$someDate = '2015-06-09';
$result = \DB::select(
    \DB::raw("SELECT count(*) as total FROM items WHERE DATE(w_laporan) = :someDate"),
    ['someDate' => $someDate]
);
```

[Check Raw Expression](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queries#raw-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
DB::table('laporan')
    ->whereRaw('date(w_laporan) = date(?)', [$timestamp])
    ->get();
```